# SQL - Grouping and counting character in two columns

Tags: sql, group-by, grouping

I have this table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      NAME           |     GENDER       |     JOB          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      John           |     Male         |    Accountant    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Jane           |     Female       |    Accountant    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Stephen        |     Male         |    Sales         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      James          |     Male         |    Accountant    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Hanna          |     Female       |    Sales         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Joe            |     Male         |    Sales         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Diana          |     Female       |    Sales         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

...and I would like to obtain a table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      JOB            |     MALE         |     FEMALE       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Accountant     |       2          |    1             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Sales          |       2          |    2             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So I tried with group by, but I'm looking for the shorter and simpler query

Comment: Please tag this post with the db engine you are using

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select job,
       sum(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as num_males,
       sum(case when gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as num_females
from t
group by job;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` for this:

#### Setup

```
DECLARE @data as Table
(
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    Gender varchar(10) not null,
    Job varchar(10) not null
)
INSERT INTO @data (Name, Gender, Job)
VALUES ('John','Male','Accountant'),
('Jane','Female','Accountant'),
('Stephen','Male','Sales'),
('James','Male','Accountant'),
('Hanna','Female','Sales'),
('Joe','Male','Sales'),
('Diana','Female','Sales')
```

#### Query:

> replace @data with your table reference

```
SELECT Job, Male = SUM(Male), Female = SUM(Female)
FROM @data
PIVOT
(
    SUM ( Gender ) FOR
    Gender IN ( Male, Female )
) as pvtData
GROUP BY Job
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged your database, but if it's `MySQL`, this would be the "shortest". Having said that, I recommend using explicit case statements than relying on syntactical quirks to handle conditionals.

```
select job
      ,sum(gender = 'Male') num_males
      ,sum(gender = 'Female') num_females
from t
group by job;
```